# Low kick and block with shank-bone

Tags: muay-thai, kicking, kickboxing, anatomy

I can't find relevant info about this matter. The thing is, I found this picture to get more detailed info about anatomy of the bone it self at the shank part of the lag and found this:

[image]

I) Is this actually the bone we use for low kick? If so, then it used also for the defense(block) right? If so, this is very odd, the bone looks very thin 
[image]

II) What is this bone? Looks like this one should be used for low-kick, he-he.

*please add ''low kick'' tag:)

Comment: Bone II is the [tibia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leg_bone).  Are you asking why muay thai fighters don't execute a low round kick with the tibia?  The kick you posted could only be executed with the frontal part of the leg as the point of contact.  If you kicked with the tibia instead, it would be a different kick.  Maybe you mean, why don't MT fighters do a low hook-kick instead of a round kick? Please clarify.

Comment: Oh... so you mean the kick with this tibia is actually the kick from the other side of the leg(the back side - "gastrocnemius muscle"), right? And correct me if I'm wrong, the block is also done with the frontal part of the leg. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I'm saying the tibia is the rear bone of the leg, and therefore would not be in a position to deliver a round kick or to block one.  That said, now that you've clarified, I believe I can answer your question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Round Kick**

You're delivering the kick with the lower part your [fibula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leg_bone).  You would also block a low round kick by turning your fibula to meet the fibula of the opponent. The tibia, while potentially stronger than the fibula, is located on the [posterior](http://kneestability.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/3/6/3036083/1467011.jpg) in relation to the Fibula.  It would therefore be in no position to deliver a low round kick.

**Hook Kick**

You *could* deliver a low [hook kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPHuldgoq44), but a hook kick typically makes contact with the heel rather than any part of the leg.  If you make contact with the tibia, you are more in a position to deliver a sweep than a true kick.

**It isn't As Weak as it looks**

Please observe the picture you posted.  Notice how the blocker has her foot planted and has all her body structure aligned with the fibula to meet the round kick.

Due to extreme [leg conditioning](http://www.muay-thai-guy.com/wp-content/uploads/1508609_10154831426990858_3559893024167704745_n.jpg), Muay Thai fighters have dense bones in their legs and their pain receptors are less active.

**But it can break**

Because of the aforementioned leg conditioning, it is possible to snap the leg of an opponent from delivering a well placed kicked to their fibula.  It is also possible to snap *your own* leg on a well-placed block like the one in the picture you posted.  I'm going to go ahead and include [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw_jcnFPfxU), but it is hard to watch, so exercise discretion.  As far as I know, this is live footage from a MT fight.  So, your initial assessment of the weakness of the fibula does have a basis in reality.

Comment: Wow, this is hard to watch. But this is actually the thing I was heard about - that people brake legs because of this blocks and in muay thai they use it very carefully and more to the upper body(to avoid the leg-block). But it's confusing to me... how is this block actually done? with the same part of the leg or with combination of the back part(if so, how?!). It's even more confusing now(kidding), but I really appreciate your help! thanks!)

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  If you want an answer to "How is this block actually done?" I recommend posting a new question, because it is significantly different from this question.  Don't forget, you can upvote answers and questions that you like (Hint: mine).  Please [take the tour](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how our site works.

Answer (score 0):

You do deliver a round kick with the thick bone. The tibia (thick bone) is anterior (in front), and the fibula (thin bone) is posteriolateral (behind, to the outside). The reason it looks reversed in that diagram is because you’re looking at the back of the leg. The crest of the tibia (what people usually mean by “the shin”) is the striking surface for a Muay Thai round kick. It’s not very difficult to look this stuff up. In order to deliver a kick with the fibula, you’d have to land it with the outside part of your calf, and you would be hitting them through a layer of calf muscle, unlike during a kick with the tibia. An outside crescent kick delivered incorrectly might be the only time that happens.